# socket.io return Transport unknown error through nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my Nodejs server by Nginx.

my server runs on port 3000 and my Nodejs client successfully connects to the server using https://example.com:3000, while https://example.com/socket.io returns:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

I used certbot for SSL certification and it configured my nginx.conf

this is Nginx .conf file for my socket.io server:

```
upstream nodesocket {
        server  127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             example.com www.example.com;

        access_log              /var/log/nginx/access-ssl.log;
        error_log               /var/log/nginx/error-ssl.log;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; 

        ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers             RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        keepalive_timeout       60;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout     10m;

        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;


        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass              https://nodesocket;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

and this is my socket io server:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')
var fs = require('fs')

var options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem')
}

var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = socketIo(server);


server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on :3000');
  });
```

I checked nodejs and nginx logs but there were no related logs and no error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and this worked for me

I deleted `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

and here is my nginx.conf

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/;
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but still I am facing {"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}